# Can geth sync only up to a specific block number?

Tags: go-ethereum

Does geth have a mode where you can tell it to sync only up to a particular block number and then stop syncing (and still serve queries about the blocks it has)?  Or a mode where you can tell it to always stay N blocks behind the latest mainnet block?  Or a mode where it says running but only syncs up to block numbers that it's given dynamically?

(Or - does geth have fine-grained control over when to accept a new block?)

Comment: no, but you can try to insert a `time.Sleep()` function somewhere in the sources to achieve the desired behavior

Answer (score 2):

Geth hasn't options in command line for it. But you can above control sync(calling `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_syncing","params":[],"id":1}`) and exit to geth process when it has needed blocks. And after you could start it without connection with other peers if you dont want receive new blocks.

Comment: I don't know how you could use eth_syncing to do this.  It tells you when geth is syncing, but doesn't give you any ability to control syncing (other than killing the process, I guess).  If you want to sync to block 10000, stop, then advance to block 11000, I don't see how eth_syncing helps you.  (There's a timing issue, so even if you start at block 0 and wait until you see block 10000, then kill the process, there's no way to ensure that you didn't sync to block 10001.)